# jQuery Validate - Success event?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using the [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin on my site, and then submitting the form via ajax. Is there an event I can use when the *entire* form is valid?

Answer (score 14):

There is no event for this. Just check the status using a simple if statement.

```
if($("form").valid()) {
 //go ahead
}
```

But, if you are trying to have a workaround solution to catch the valid event, you can do something like this

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    if($(this).valid()) {
       //go ahead
    } else {
       //do some error handling
    }
});
```

Comment: Out of interest: In your second code snippet, would you be better off using $(this) instead of $("form") in case there are multiple <form> elements on the page?

Comment: @MattHamilton, You are absolutely correct. I was answering on terms of forms. I updated my answers :)

Comment: Cool. I'm learning this stuff so it's good to know that some of it is sinking in. :)

Comment: This method results in validation being called twice when you submit a form to a .net server application as the form submission itself has an additional handler applied to it by the framework which also does this. The correct way is to take @Ryley's approach above.

Answer (score 9):

The way jQuery Validate wants you to deal with this is by specifying a `submitHandler` aka "run this function when the form is submitted AND it is valid".  You would submit the contents of the form via AJAX from within that function.

```
$('form').validate({
    //your normal options
    submitHandler: function(){
        $.ajax(...);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is correct way and should be used if you are using jquery validator

Answer (score 3):

Just call

```
$("form").valid(); // returns true if valid
```

and not

```
$("form").validate(); //returns $.validate
```

Answer (score 2):

you can implement similar things like this:

```js
var validator = $("#signin_form").validate({
        rules: {
            Phone: {
                required: true,
                phone: true
            },
            VerifyCode: {
                required: true,
                verifyCode: true
            }
        },
        messages: {},
        success: function (label, element) {
            if (validator.numberOfInvalids() == 0) {
                console.log(true);
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

`valid( )` Checks whether the selected form is valid or whether all selected elements are valid.

### edit

Returns: `Boolean`

Comment: This is too vague, not constructively helpful, one line "see this" answers are also against the spirit of SO's community, please improve this answer.