# Pop-up message after validation is successful in bbPress (with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, bbpress

I would like to display a pop up message if users submit a topic or a reply successfully.

I tried to following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bbp_topic_submit").click(function(event) {
         alert("Thank you very much! Your topic has been successfully submitted!");
    });
});
```

It works well but it triggers a pop up message every time when clicking "Submit" even if validation is not successful.

So I want to make it done after validation is successful. I trid to the following script by referring to [jQuery Validate - Success event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027110/jquery-validate-success-event) but it didn't work (nothing happens).

```
$("form#new-post").submit(function() {
    if($(this).valid()) {
// 
    }
});
```

How can I display a pop up message only if validation is successful?

Comment: please clarify "what didn't work" ?

Comment: @DinoMyte. Thanks for your comment. The pop-up message is displayed whenever a user clicks on "Submit" when using the first script above.

Comment: If the "validate" script is used, nothing happens.

Comment: refer to the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the [submitHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#options) `callback` handler to determine if the `form` `validation` was successful or not.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("form").validate({
       submitHandler: function() { alert("Thank you very much! Your topic has been successfully submitted!"); }
     });
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/5RrGa/1627/

Comment: Thank you very much. I just test it but it won't work as well.. (I think I also tried a similar script. It's very strange...) I will review it later carefully again with the script you suggested. Really thanks for your kindness.

Comment: Really thanks for your help. I enqueued jquery.validate.min.js and the pop-up message appears after successful validation when clicking on "Submit". However, even if I click OK (shown in the message box), the form would not be submitted. Do I need to add "$(this).submit();" or something to make the form submitted after pop-up message?